# How convert few sql select to multiple select queries

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have problem with last (3rd) dynamic dropdown list - wrong result.

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=='showAll')   
{$id = "0";}
else $id=$_POST['id'];

switch($action)
{
case 'showAll';
    $stmt=$DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM slist GROUP BY site');
    $stmt->execute();
break;
case 'site';
    $stmt=$DB_con->prepare('SELECT menu FROM slist WHERE site=:id GROUP BY menu ORDER BY menu');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
break;
case 'menu';
    $stmt=$DB_con->prepare('SELECT categ FROM slist WHERE menu=:id GROUP BY categ ORDER BY categ');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
break;
case 'categ';
    $stmt=$DB_con->prepare('SELECT links FROM slist WHERE categ=:id GROUP BY categ ORDER BY links');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
break;
default: 
    $stmt=$DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM slist GROUP BY site');
    $stmt->execute();
break;
}
?>
```

The `SELECT links FROM slist WHERE categ=:id GROUP BY categ ORDER BY links` for `$action=="categ"` returns the wrong end value (gets the result from the first available in the list), because the query should look like this: `SELECT links FROM slist WHERE menu=:id AND categ=:id GROUP BY categ ORDER BY links`.

How do I pass the value of the "menu" variable to this query?

SQL table column names and several records from table:

```
`id`, `site`, `menu`, `categ`, `links`
28, 'CoursesWeb.net', 'PHP-MySQL', 'Tutorials', 'http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/tutorials_t'
34, 'CoursesWeb.net', 'JavaScript', 'Tutorials', 'http://coursesweb.net/javascript/tutorials_t'
46, 'CoursesWeb.net', 'Flash-AS3', 'Tutorials', 'http://coursesweb.net/flash/tutorials_t'
```

Comment: Welcome to your new friend: the [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: *Now, that's a switch* @tadman

Comment: Yes, I know. I changed it. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Using `switch` starts to organize your code better and show you where you might be able to remove duplicate code, simplifying what you have and isolating the problem. What do you mean "Wrong"? What values are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: No matter what I choose, the result is first link address. Always.
I need query: `SELECT links FROM slist WHERE menu=:id AND categ=:id GROUP BY categ ORDER BY links`

Comment: Link to my demo: `goo.gl/fqr6jc`

Comment: try using mysqli instead of PDO.

Comment: What will this change? @dean

Comment: you will still have the same results , nothing will change. but its simpler to understand and to find any error if a problem arise.